# Disable button if certain number of checkbox are checked

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i have a template each have some checkboxes:

```
<input class="general" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="about" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="money" type="checkbox"/>
```

And i have this button too:

```
<button class="disable" {{action "filter"}}>Filter</button>
```

In the controller of this template, i'm trying to remove the class disable if one or more checkbox are clicked, but more than that, i need to know each checkbox are clicked.

I'm relative new in the Ember word... and i really try to make it work, but i don't understand very much to do so.. I was trying like this:

```
OBS: I was trying to enable the button.


export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  checkbox: 0,

  allowFilter: Ember.computed('checkbox', function() {
    let result = false;

    this.get('checkbox') ? result = true : result = false;
    return result;
  }),

  actions: {
    checkboxClicked () {
      this.get('checkbox') =+ 1;
    },

    filter () {

    }
  }
});
```

And in the button:

```
<button class="{{if allowFilter "" "disable"}}" {{action "filter"}}>Filter</button>
```

But.. well.. didn't worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use the `{{input checked=isChecked}}` helper and then in your component you can do this to check if is checked or not

```
  actions: {
    checkedButton: function() {
      // Do whatever you want with the data (ie, save it)
      var isChecked = this.get('isChecked');
      alert('true or false? ' + isChecked);//if is checked will get true otherwise false
    }
```

There is a lot of examples about this: [fist example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kiwijowe/9/edit?html,css,js,output), [second example](http://alexdiliberto.com/posts/ember-toggle-all-checkbox/) and [third example.](http://jsbin.com/zubehejaye/edit?html,js,output)Check them out